# I wrote a Wordpress Plugin Shortcode and it gives me a Header Allready sent error when i try to update a page with that shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, shortcode

i just wrote a plugin that should display a table with `acf fields` (mostly taxonomies) via `shortcode` for a better intern linking. everything works fine. but when i add the `shortcode` to a page and try to update it i get `PHP Errors`:

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at wp-content/plugins/pwd-taxo-tables/taxo.php:64) in /wp-admin/post.php on line 222
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at wp-content/plugins/pwd-taxo-tables/taxo.php:64) in wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1251
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at wp-content/plugins/pwd-taxo-tables/taxo.php:64) in /wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1254

Any idea whats wrong on the code?

```
// register jquery and style on initialization
add_action('init', 'register_script');
function register_script() {

    wp_register_style( 'new_style', plugins_url('/css/pwd.css', __FILE__), false, '1.0.0', 'all');
}

// use the registered jquery and style above
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_style');

function enqueue_style(){

    wp_enqueue_style( 'new_style' );
}



function pwd_get_taxonomy_links($taxonomy){
    $terms = get_field($taxonomy);

    if($terms) {
        foreach ($terms as $term){
            $termdata = get_term_by('id',$term,$taxonomy);
            $taxname = $termdata->name;
            $taxurl = get_term_link($term,$taxonomy);
            $alltaxlinks .= '<a href="'.$taxurl.'">'.$taxname.'</a>, ';

        }
        echo rtrim($alltaxlinks, ', ');
    }

}

function method1($a,$b)
{
    return ($a["menu_order"] <= $b["menu_order"]) ? -1 : 1;
}
function get_tax_vale(){

    $fields = get_fields();
    //echo "<pre>" . print_r($fields) . "</pre>";

  /*  foreach ($fields as $name => $value){
        $fielddata = get_field_object($name);
        $fields[$name]['menu_order']= $fielddata['menu_order'];
    }
*/
    //echo "<pre>" . print_r($fields) . "</pre>";
  //  uasort($fields, "method1");
    //print_r($fields);
    if($fields){
        echo '<table class="table table-details table-condensed" style="font-size:0.7rem;"><tbody>';

        foreach( $fields as $name => $value ){

            $fielddata = get_field_object($name);
            $label = $fielddata['label'];
            $type = $fielddata['type'];
            $order = $fielddata['menu_order'];

            if($name != "einleitung" && $name != "affiliate_link" && $name != "menu_order"){
                echo '<tr><td><span class="">' . $label . '</span></td><td>';

                if($type != "taxonomy"){
                    echo $value;
                }
                else{
                    pwd_get_taxonomy_links($name);
                }

                echo '</td><td><a target="_blank" class="tax-button" href="' . get_field('affiliate_link') . '">Zum Anbieter</a> </td></tr>';

            }



        }
        echo ' </tbody></table>';

    }


}

add_shortcode('taxotable', 'get_tax_vale');
```

Comment: Line 64 in this code would be here:  echo '<table class="table table-details table-condensed" style="font-size:0.7rem;"><tbody>';  ...but i dont know whats wrong with it?

Comment: Try returning a string instead of echoing in place. That function is being called before the header information is, which is disrupting the flow of the site.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this code**

The reason here is that your function for add_shortcode must return a value, and not output it directly.

```
    function get_tax_vale(){

        $fields = get_fields();

        if($fields){
            $htmlscript = '<table class="table table-details table-condensed" style="font-size:0.7rem;"><tbody>';

            foreach( $fields as $name => $value ){

                $fielddata = get_field_object($name);
                $label = $fielddata['label'];
                $type = $fielddata['type'];
                $order = $fielddata['menu_order'];

                if($name != "einleitung" && $name != "affiliate_link" && $name != "menu_order"){
                    $htmlscript .= '<tr><td><span class="">' . $label . '</span></td><td>';

                    if($type != "taxonomy"){
                        $htmlscript .=  $value;
                    }
                    else{
                        $htmlscript .= pwd_get_taxonomy_links($name);
                    }

                    $htmlscript .=  '</td><td><a target="_blank" class="tax-button" href="' . get_field('affiliate_link') . '">Zum Anbieter</a> </td></tr>';

                }
            }
            $htmlscript .=  ' </tbody></table>';
        }

     return $htmlscript;
    }
    add_shortcode('taxotable', 'get_tax_vale');
```

Comment: Best to explain the difference rather than just dump a bunch of changed code. The reason here is that your function for `add_shortcode` must return a value, and not output it directly.